# Importing previously generated r object into Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I hope this question is meaningful and appropriate for here:

Essentially I am writing code within a Rmd file that includes a data randomization simulation which is a very long for loop.  This process takes quite some time to complete (>2 minutes - it's a big simulation). I store the results and then use these results to analyze and visualize in various ways throughout the Rmd report.

However, when creating and editing the report I might want to see how my code and text edits alter the html output.   Each time that I execute the knitr:html command I have to sit through another 2 minutes of data randomization.   This can obviously be frustratingly slow.

Is there a way of performing the for-loop process once outside of the Rmd file, store the results and then just import these results into the Rmd file.  I'm pretty sure that Rmd cannot import from the global environment.  I wonder if anyone knows of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the results of your simulation to an `rds` file using [`saveRDS`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/saveRDS).  Then add a call to `readRDS` at the top of your `Rmd` file.  You probably want to do this in a block with `echo = FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to cache the results generated from each 'chunk'

Do refer to the menu.

http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/

I hope you using RStudio, caching is much easier

Alternatively,

Do check out using IPython with R. https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=using%20Ipython%20with%20R
By default, all data generated in each cell in IPython (regardless of R/Python) will be cached in each cell and shareable between cells.

Comment: Good point, though if it's a long simulation, having a more permanent way of storing the result than caching is a sensible idea.

Comment: @RichieCotton Yes saving R object as .rds file will be good for large R objects or objects that requires a long time to be generated. It do take a longer them to read and write the .rds file rather than to just keeping it in the memory (like what cache does)